# Test Apex Code: How to emulate a SOQL call that has a related object?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

For Apex testing, I'm trying to create an object that is the same as the one created with a SOQL statement (see following method).  The method retrieves the `Quote_To_Lease__c` object from Salesforce and gets a Related List (`Referral_Payment_Transaction__r`).  When I try to create this object and related list (see following test code) in Salesforce I get a syntax error "Field is Not Writeable: `Referral_Payment_Transactions__r`".

### Is there a way to create a fake object which has a related list that looks like the real one created by a SOQL select?

**Method**

```
public static void getQtlWithRpTrans(){
    Quote_to_Lease__c qtl =
    [SELECT Id, Name 
        ,Opportunity__c, Opportunity__r.Name, Opportunity__r.Referred_By_Lookup__c, Opportunity__r.Property_Name__c
        , (select id, Name, FirstName__c, LastName__c, Status__c, Referral_Type__c 
            , Event_Name__c, Customer_Name__c, Email__c, Cost_Center__c, ExtId_Vendor_Account__c, Unit__c 
            , Date_Forwarded__c, Date_Fwd_Completed__c
            ,Contact__c, Lead__c, Opportunity__c, Referral_Payment_Account__c
        from Referral_Payment_Transactions__r) 
    FROM Quote_to_Lease__c
    where id = 'a0mQ0000003sM6wIAE'];
    Referral_Payment_Transaction__c rpTrans = qtl.Referral_Payment_Transactions__r[0];
    System.debug('Qtl=' + qtl.id
        + ', rpTrans=' + rpTrans.Id
        + ', rpTrans.DateForwarded=' + rpTrans.Date_Forwarded__c
    );
}
```

**Test code**

```
// Create fake QTL object
    Quote_To_Lease__c qtl = new Quote_to_lease__c(
        id = RpTransQtl.fakeQtlId
        , name='L12345'
    );

    // Create fake RpTrans object
    Referral_Payment_Transaction__c rpTrans = 
        new Referral_Payment_Transaction__c(
            Id=RpTransQtl.fakeRpTransId
    );
    // Create a list to place in the related field
    List<Referral_Payment_Transaction__c> myRpTransList = 
        new List<Referral_Payment_Transaction__c>();
    myRpTransList.add(rpTrans);

    // Get syntax error on following line
    //   Field is not writeable: Referral_Payment_Transactions__r 
    qtl.Referral_Payment_Transactions__r = myRpTransList;
```

Comment: SOQL is a query language. It does not create objects. That said, you may perhaps be looking to use __c rather than __r to fetch the ID for your related object, which you'd use to set up the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Create was the wrong word, retrieve the data from Salesforce using SOQL would have been better.  Once the data is retrieved, the code will evaluate the fields in the object and related list.  My challenge is to emulate that same object and related list in test code so I can check out my code's functionality without having to create an object with an insert.

Comment: __c did not work - invalid field.

Comment: Okay. Again, you cannot assign a value to the to-many relationship field. Your code should create one (or more) child objects, then assign the parent's ID to the lookup field on each child object.

Comment: The structure of the object in question did not formal well in my first post.  
Here is a simpler form in a Select SOQL Select statement which works:
SELECT Id, Name 
 , (select id, Name
   from Referral_Payment_Transactions__r) 
FROM Quote_to_Lease__c

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant here. You are trying to create some test objects in a parent-child relationship, right? That means you create the parent first, then use the parent's ID in the lookup field of each child object.

Comment: This is only for testing.  When I say create one, I'm talking about creating an object in my test code and not one in Salesforce DB.  My goal is to use a handmade object in the test code that has a related list that has the same form as the one that a SOQL statement would retrieve.  So what you are saying is that is is impossible to create an object structure similar to the SOQL structure without inserting the components into the DB?  The object that I'm working with have 4 related objects that I must create so I was trying to short-cut this work by just creating a test object.

Comment: The structure is not parent-child, but object and related list.  It is just like the following Account-Contact relationship: SELECT Id, Name 
 , (select id, name from contacts) 
FROM Account

Comment: When you create and insert an object in test code, it is immediately deleted by the system following the test. It is as though it was never created.

Comment: Related lists are always parent-child relationships. There are really only two relationship types: lookup and master detail. Both are types of parent-child relationships.

Comment: @CaspNZ faking a DML means you can skip the time spent running triggers, validation rules, etcetera when you don't need to.

Comment: True, but if that field is not writeable, what other options do you have?

Comment: @CaspNZ The JSON parser is immune to immutable fields-- see my answer for how I'd accomplish this task.

Comment: Just for info, the above has been copy pasted and presented as a YouTube video by someone who's not keen on real work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYDGVgGg3ws

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simulate a query in JSON.

For your viewing pleasure, I present the following:

```
Quote_to_Lease__c[] qol = (Quote_to_Lease__c[])JSON.deserialize(
    '[{"Id":"Real-looking-id", "Name": "001", "Referral_Payment_Transactions__r":['+
    '{"totalSize":1,"done":true, "records":[{"Id":"Another-real-Id","Name":"002"}]}'+
    ']}]',
    List<Quote_to_Lease__c>.class
);
```

Also included is this real code I used in my developer org to arrive at this answer:

```
Account a = (Account)JSON.deserialize('{"Name":"Test", "Contacts": {"totalSize":1, "done":true, "records":[{"FirstName":"Brian","LastName":"Fear"}]}}', Account.class);
```

You can also build your own multi-level map, JSON-ify it, then deserialize it back into the desired target, if you wanted to.

Comment: I should have remembered this ...as I've used the equivalent when deserializing REST SOQL GET from a remote SFDC into a local SFDC.

Comment: That's a smokin' hot answer! What a cunning plan. I'll be using the technique in the future.

Comment: We are making heavy use of a class called *SObjectFactory* which does leverage the JSON approach. It allows us to set parent and child objects and formula/rollup-summary fields. This does result in lean and fast tests (sometimes by factor 10), because we do not need to insert everything into the database. It also allows to write much better unit tests, if there is no trigger ruining your test data on insert. Without it, good testing with APEX is not manageable.

Comment: and in the smoking hot vein, you can put the JSON into a staticResource as it is much easier to build/edit JSON outside of APEX strings and then do a SOQL Select on the static resource to fetch the JSON for deserializing

Comment: and, this smoking hot answer also solves this problem - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/49317/2602

Comment: I am using this to upsert a bunch of related records via a custom REST API but I have a problem accessing the nested records. The problem is, when I try to retrieve any child records, like so:
    `for (Contact c: a.Contacts)`
....the list of child records is never found. Looking in debug output, I see that it uses a QueryLocatorIterator object and the deserialized list of records never make it in there (Returning zero for totalNumRecords).
Note that my example is actually all custom objects; not sure if that makes a diff.

Answer (score 2):

SFDC Apex can use the relationship field differently when constructing objects depending on use case

```
// Account has related list of Contacts
Account a = new Account();
a.contacts = new List<Contact> {new Contact()}; // fails - can't add related list

// Contact has a parent Account
Contact c = new Contact();
c.account = new Account();  // works, can add parent obj
```

In your scenario, you are trying to build the relatedlist without actually doing DML in your testmethod. As you have seen, this does not work without using the json.deserialize approach shown by @sfdcfox.

Comment: There is a way, where there's a will.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the relationships in your test data.  Here's a simple example of an object (program) with a child object (state program):

```
Program_Cycle__c pc = new Program_Cycle__c();
pc.Name = 'Test';
pc.Fiscal_Year__c = '2012';
pc.Type__c = 'Summer';
insert pc;
...
//State Program
// just gets a mostly pre-filled object
StateProgram__c objTestStateProgram1 = TestMethodClass.getStateProgram(); 
objTestStateProgram1.Program_Cycle__c = pc.Id;  //AAA

List<StateProgram__c> lstStateProgram = new List<StateProgram__c>();
lstStateProgram.add(objTestStateProgram1);
insert lstStateProgram;  //BBB
```

Each relationship must be set **and** added to the database.  Adding the ID of the program to the state program (line AAA) isn't enough.  It must be added to the database as well (line BBB).  If the relationships are more complex (eg. junction objects), those objects would need to be filled out with the correct IDs and saved as well.