# How can I mock a query of ApexClass for testing?

Tags: apex, soql, class, reflection

While recently working on a large project where unit test executions would run upwards of 2 hours, we realized we could get a performance gain by avoiding touching the database (e.g. SOQL and DML) during our tests.

So if we wanted to work with Accounts, we might have some code like this:

```
public class AccountDao
{
    @testVisible private static List<Account> mockResultList = null;  // Does NOT support multiple queries of same SObject in same test!

    public static List<Account> getList() 
    {
        if (mockResultList != null) { System.debug (LoggingLevel.WARN, '!!!!! Unit test uses Account mockResultList: ' + mockResultList); }     

        List<Account> accountList = (Test.isRunningTest() && (mockResultList != null))
                                        ? mockResultList
                                        : [SELECT id, name FROM Account];

        return accountList;
    }
}
}
```

... where we could feed the expected result into mockResultList before testing the code which would execute AccountDao.getList().

This works fine for our purposes.

But now I am trying to do the same for an ApexClass query.

If I have some Apex class (e.g. a class named "MyClass"), is it possible to somehow add some representation of this to a `List<ApexClass>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApexClass is a standard SObject that has fields such as Id, Name, Body, CreatedDate. This executes fine in the developer console:

```
ApexClass c = new ApexClass(Name = 'MyClass');
System.debug('>>> c=' + c);
```

So it looks like you can mock these just as you can any other SObject.

However, if using the real SObjects isn't causing a performance problem then your testing will potentially be more representative if you stick to the real SObjects with their hard to mock underlying behaviours.

Comment: This looks very promising!  Will try it.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

We faced the same problem and went down a different path:

We are mocking the DAO classes (and everything else as well). A typical implementation does look like the following:

```
public virtual with sharing class AccountDao {

    public virtual List<Account> getAccounts() {
        //SOQL query
    }
}

public virtual with sharing class AccountModifier {

    @TestVisible private AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao();

    public void doStuff() {
        List<Account> accounts = accountDao.getAccounts();
    }
}

@isTest
private class AccountModifierTest {

    class AccountDaoMock extends AccountDao {

        private List<Account> accounts;

        AccountDaoMock(List<Account> accounts) {
            this.accounts = accounts;
        }

        private Boolean getAccountsHasBeenVisited;
        public override List<Account> getAccounts() {
            getAccountsHasBeenVisited = true;

            return accounts;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testDoStuff() {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>(); //populate list as needed

        AccountDaoMock accountDao = new AccountDaoMock(accounts);

        AccountModifier modifier = new AccountModifier();

        modifier.accountDao = accountDao;

        Test.startTest();

        modifier.doStuff();

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(true, accountDao.getAccountsHasBeenVisited);

        // further asserts
    }
}
```

This approach produces lean, readable code.

The list of ApexClass could be mocked using the JSON conversion [described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49216/test-apex-code-how-to-emulate-a-soql-call-that-has-a-related-object).

Comment: I really like this approach.   I actually was thinking about playing with "virtual" to enable mocking, but I haven't investigated virtual classes much.  As I understand SFDC, by default (unlike Java), classes are "final" and "virtual" changes this, but still (unlike abstract) allows for executable code.  Are there any drawbacks to making a class virtual?  Anything SFDC won't allow you to do with the virtual class that you can with a default/final class?